# p:dataExporter exporting all dataTables instead of just the targeted dataTable component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, apache-poi

I am querying data from a database, and presenting the results in a    separate <p:dataTable/> for each result.  I am using an    <p:accordionPanel> with multiple <p:tab/> to hold this list of    results.  Each result is under a separate tab, and uses a    <p:dataTable/> to display its values.  I have customized the tab    title using <f:facet/>, and each title contains a <p:commandButton/>    with a <p:dataExporter/> component to help me export(in xls format)    the <p:dataTable/> in the associated <p:tab/>.  In each    <p:dataExporter/> component I have targeted the <p:dataTable/>    contained in that associated tab whose title it is situated in. When    I try to export any one <p:dataTable/> in xls format using the    <p:dataExporter> in its tab, it creates a worksheet for every one of    the <p:dataTable/> inside the <p:accordionPanel/> instead of just its    targeted <p:dataTable/>.

The <p:dataExporter/> component in primefaces utilizes the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/) library for exporting a <p:dataTable /> into different formats. I am trying to debug an issue with the xls format. It seems that the expected behavior is that each <p:dataExporter/> component when triggered should create a separate [HSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) with a [HSSFSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html) representing the targeted <p:dataTable/>. Here is what is happening,

- When I try to look at the state of the HSSFWorkbook in the postprocessor for the <p:dataExporter/> through the object implicitly passed through in the server side function, I noticed that the workbook contains multiple sheets, one for each <p:dataTable/> in the <p:accordionPanel/>
- The name of each sheet in the downloaded xls file is equal to the id of the <p:dataTable/> in the
- facelets file (not the client id which has all information of the accordionPanel and the tab prepended to it, to make the <p:dataTable/> unique) plus an index 1,2,3 denoting the tab placement.
- When I take a look at the actual DataTableExcelExporter class in primefaces responsible for exporting the <p:dataTable/>, I noticed that the doExport function that creates those sheets is called more than once, one for each <p:dataTable/> instead of just the <p:dataTable/> that was targeted by the <p:dataExporter/> component.
- Now I can do things to manipulate the HSSFSheets in the postprocessor server side callback, and remove the unwanted sheets, but I do not think this is the right way to go. Plus I am also using a csv exporter, and the result in that exporter is that information for every <p:dataTable/> gets mushed up in a single file.
- I looked up the error chain when I was getting Sheet naming conflicts for results which have the same name from the query, and it seems that the <p:accordionPanel/> and <p:tab/> component broadcasts any event (like click) to its surrounding, and inner components, so was thinking if this might be the root cause of the problem.

**Facelets**

```
             <p:accordionPanel class="search-results-panel" id="searchResultsPanel" rendered="true" multiple="true" value="#{deepBean.searchResults}" var="searchResult">
                    <p:tab closable="true" id="tab#{deepBean.searchResults.indexOf(searchResult)}">
                        <f:facet name="title">
                            <p:outputPanel class="search-results-tab-grid">
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{searchResult.searchName}" 
                                               style="margin-right: 20px;"
                                               class="search-results-tab-name"/>
                                <p:outputPanel class="search-results-tab-num">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{searchResult.data.size()}" class="number-records" style="font-size: 1.5em; padding-right: 10px;"/>
                                    <p:outputLabel value=" Records"/>
                                </p:outputPanel>
                                <p:outputPanel class="search-results-tab-exports">
                                    <p:commandButton value="xls" process="@this">
                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{deepBean.searchResults.indexOf(searchResult)}" target="#{deepBean.searchResultToExport}"/>
                                        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="#{deepBean.getExportDatatableId(searchResult)}" 
                                                        fileName="#{searchResult.searchName}-results" 
                                                        postProcessor="#{deepBean.preProcessDoc}"/>
                                    </p:commandButton> 
                                    <p:commandButton value="csv" process="@this">
                                        <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="#{deepBean.getExportDatatableId(searchResult)}" 
                                                        fileName="#{searchResult.searchName}-results" />
                                    </p:commandButton>
                                    <p:commandButton value="pdf" process="@this">
                                        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="#{deepBean.getExportDatatableId(searchResult)}" 
                                                        fileName="#{searchResult.searchName}-results" />
                                    </p:commandButton>
                                    <p:commandButton value="txt" process="@this">
                                        <p:dataExporter type="txt" target="#{deepBean.getExportDatatableId(searchResult)}" 
                                                        fileName="#{searchResult.searchName}-results" />
                                    </p:commandButton>
                                </p:outputPanel>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:dataTable value="#{searchResult.data}" 
                                     rowIndexVar="rowIdx"
                                     emptyMessage="Run a Search to Populate this"
                                     scrollRows="10"
                                     var="resultsMap"
                                     scrollable="true"
                                     scrollHeight="400"
                                     style="overflow-x: auto"
                                     >
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{searchResult.searchName}-results"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:columns value="#{searchResult.resultColumns}" 
                                       var="columnName"
                                       headerText="#{columnName}"
                                       width="auto"
                                       style="white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;"
                                       filterable="true"
                                       filterMatchMode="contains"
                                       sortable="true"
                                       >
                                <f:facet name="filter">

                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{resultsMap.get(columnName)}"/>
                            </p:columns>
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Returned #{searchResult.data.size()} results"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>
```

**Primefaces DataTableExcelExport doExport function**

```
@Override
    public void doExport(FacesContext context, DataTable table, ExportConfiguration exportConfiguration, int index) throws IOException {
        String sheetName = getSheetName(context, table);
        if (sheetName == null) {
            sheetName = table.getId() + (index + 1);
        }

        sheetName = WorkbookUtil.createSafeSheetName(sheetName);
        if ("empty".equals(sheetName) || "null".equals(sheetName)) {
            sheetName = "Sheet (" + (index + 1) + ")";
        }

        ExcelOptions options = (ExcelOptions) exportConfiguration.getOptions();
        if (options == null) {
            stronglyTypedCells = true;
        }
        else {
            stronglyTypedCells = options.isStronglyTypedCells();
        }
        Sheet sheet = createSheet(wb, sheetName, options);
        applyOptions(wb, table, sheet, options);
        exportTable(context, table, sheet, exportConfiguration);

        if (options == null || options.isAutoSizeColumn()) {
            short colIndex = 0;
            for (UIColumn col : table.getColumns()) {
                if (col instanceof DynamicColumn) {
                    ((DynamicColumn) col).applyStatelessModel();
                }

                if (col.isRendered() && col.isExportable()) {
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(colIndex);
                    colIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error**

```
SEVERE:   The workbook already contains a sheet named 'test-search-results'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet named 'test-search-results'
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:939)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:124)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.export.DataTableExcelExporter.createSheet(DataTableExcelExporter.java:394)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.export.DataTableExcelExporter.doExport(DataTableExcelExporter.java:93)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.export.DataTableExporter$DataTableVisitCallBack.visit(DataTableExporter.java:365)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:127)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:691)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.visitTree(UITabPanel.java:1006)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.export.DataTableExporter$DataTableVisitCallBack.lambda$invoke$0(DataTableExporter.java:384)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.invokeOnClosestIteratorParent(ComponentUtils.java:530)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.export.DataTableExporter$DataTableVisitCallBack.invoke(DataTableExporter.java:382)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.export.DataTableExporter.export(DataTableExporter.java:326)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:165)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:490)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:211)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.broadcast(UITabPanel.java:1197)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1396)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:58)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1637)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: It looks like your `target` value is wrong.  the `target` should be the ID of the datatable to export. So give your table an `id` value and set target to that `id`

Comment: The target value is correctly targeting the datatable to export. The callback function in the server side calculates the client side id for the datatable.

Comment: Right but the fact that you are doing it inside an "iterating" component like accordion tab panels tells me something is not right and that is why its finding ALL of your datatables.  You have to to some debugging....

Comment: Even if I provide an id for the datatable, since its inside an iterating component, the client side will automatically prepend the iterating container id, and the tab index automatically to make the datatable unique, hence why I calculate the id on the server side. If I just use that id on the target, it will create a HSSFSheet naming conflict now since it again tries to export every datatable with the same name using that common id. Let me know if I am missing something here or any suggestions how to debug this through.

Comment: off the top of my head I don't have any good ideas. It feels like the problem is somewhere in the exporter code when its lookup up its target.  Could be a bug?